# Active class not applied to certain menu items

Tags: php, jquery, css

I feel like an idiot because I asked a very similar question earlier today, but now that I've gone to apply it again, I'm running into a similar issue.

I'm working with a blog template using PHP to load page elements from the database. Here's a built menu and a the `.active` style based on my PHP:

```
<div role="navigation" id="menu">
          <div class="page-menu">
        <ul>
                  <li class="list-item"><a href="/anchor/posts" title="Posts">Posts</a></li>
                  <li class="list-item"><a href="/anchor/demo-page-3" title="Demo Page 3">Demo Page 3</a></li>
                  <li class="list-item"><a href="/anchor/demo-page-4" title="Demo Page 4">Demo Page 4</a></li>
                  <li class="list-item"><a href="/anchor/demo" title="demo page">demo</a></li>
                </ul>
      </div>

<style>
.active {background-color: #0d597e; }
</style>
```

Here's my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var current = location.pathname;
        $('.page-menu li a').each(function(){
          var $this = $(this);
          if($(this).attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1){
            $this.addClass('active');
          }
        })
      })
```

Now, I know it works because "Posts" has the active class added, none of the other pages do when they're clicked.

[image: The post page gets the active class, none of the others do when clicked]

I also tested with `alert(location.pathname)` and those all came back correct. Where am I going wrong? I'm pulling my hair out trying to get this sorted.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zv3y3bca/1/)**

Comment: So as I can see... The correct `active` class is added for a split second and then removed? Or is that just the `:active` state being shown?

Comment: `$(this).attr('href').indexOf(current)` - why would a value (what `.attr()` should return) have an index? Also you are never resetting your `current`

Comment: @fizzix It's just a jump in the GIF...recorded ~15fps, only export around 10. From what I can tell, the active state isn't applied.

Comment: Very hard to debug without a http://jsfiddle.net. Any chance you could do one up for us?

Comment: Does it work for demo page?

Comment: @kingkero - He is using `indexOf()`, which is completely different from `index()`. The `indexOf()` method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string, hence why he is testing it against -1 to see if it returns true or false. He is doing that part correctly. Also, he may not need to reset `current` since it may only be applied upon page load. Need a fiddle to make sure though.

Comment: @fizzix I'm rather used to see that method used in the context of arrays/sets, but you do have a valid point

Comment: Are you sure none of the other pages have the `active` class when they are clicked because a different page is loaded..? Hence, all further jQuery code is stopped to load the next page.

Comment: Here's a video of my local testing site and the console: http://www.screencast.com/t/XFBIru2S4Dt (17 secs)

Comment: Your if($(this).attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1){ won't work because anchor-demo will return 0 for all 3 demo pages but try with == current instead of indexOf

Comment: @artm has a very valid point

Comment: I just tried that, and even added another page to test on, but it still doesn't apply the class to anything other than post when I click it.

Comment: I'm guessing your jQuery selector is only selecting the first a but can't see how. Put an alert inside your each to see if it's visiting all a's.

Comment: @artm - I just did a test on the fiddle and it is definitely looping over all 4 anchor tags.

Comment: Have you tried doing a console log to test if the URL's are the exact same? For example, put the following within the `each` loop:  `console.log(current + ' ' $(this).attr('href'))`. Also try logging  to see if the `indexOf()` returns true of false.

Comment: As you can see on this fiddle, it is definitely working if the URL is correct: http://jsfiddle.net/zv3y3bca/2/. Are you able to provide us with a link of the absolute URL's of each 4 of those pages please?

Comment: Neither console.log() nor alert() are being called on any page other that Posts.

Comment: @BrianBennett - Okay... that is extremely odd. Is the DOM structure  of the navigation the EXACT same on all pages?

Comment: @fizzix They seem to be the same on the video.

Comment: @fizzix Yeah, it's called from `header.php` as part of the theme structure, so the menu never changes. The CMS has `menu_url()` which echoes out the page relative URL when it's used. I added `http://localhost:8888` to the PHP structure to make sure it was using an absolute URL, but it's still not working.

Comment: @fizzix Thanks for spending 40 minutes on this. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Haha all good @BrianBennett. Glad that you could finally get it all sorted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in console on demo-page-3 and demo-page-4 on the video that you don't get on posts page. 'Uncaught type error - Cannot read property of 'replace' of undefined. This JS error would stop the further JS from running and your menu function wouldn't get called. Fix this error and your menu will work.

Comment: Holy crap, you are my hero. I knew I had that error, but I didn't know that it stopped all scripts from running. I just moved this one to the top of the footer and it's working. **Thank you.**

Comment: @BrianBennett No worries. JS is like that, if there's an error, any following JS won't run. You should fix that error, or at least put it in try catch if you can't.

Comment: My scripting is pretty unorganized right now. Today's task is to split up the different functions so one break won't affect the others that need to run. Thanks again.